# else condition not working in appium

Tags: android, appium

I'm trying to write appium test script for android application, in one case waiting for a dialog box with Yes and No button, that dialog box won't appear always, if the dialog box appear I want to click on Yes, else not appear it will go the next case, I have written the condition below, but problem is `else` part not working. its only working while dialog is appear(`if` part).

```
if (driver.findElement(dialog).isDisplayed()){
        driver.findElement(yesBtn).click();
        waitForVisibilityOf(fab);
        return new OnBoardingFbReg(driver);
    }

    else {
        waitForVisibilityOf(fab);
        return new OnBoardingFbReg(driver);

    }
```

Comment: That is what you are doing.

Comment: description edited

Answer (score 0):

your if() is not working because if the element is not displayed, the function `isDisplayed()` returns an `Exception`. 
Please do the following:

```
try{
    if (driver.findElement(dialog).isDisplayed()){
            driver.findElement(yesBtn).click();
            waitForVisibilityOf(fab);
            return new OnBoardingFbReg(driver);
        }

    }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            waitForVisibilityOf(fab);
            return new OnBoardingFbReg(driver);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it will help

```
 if(ds.findElements( By.id("id") ).size() != 0)
{

driver.findElement(yesBtn).click();
}else
{
  System.out.println("Do the second operation");}
```

}